# What is Debugging Process

Tags: debugging, testing

I am confused a little bit here , I Know it is really very simple question , but I am not getting it properly.

What Actually Debugging process do ? On Google it says "Finding and Fixing the Software code" I am agree with Finding Error , but I am  not getting it - How you gonna fix any error while in debugging process ?

Comment: Typically, I try to avoid fixing errors while I'm debugging.

Comment: The 'debugging process' is more than just running the Debugger in your IDE.  It is describing the fact that you find the errors (possibly by using a Debugger, or possibly by reading your code, etc), resolving them, and then checking that you have actually fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging is -- literally -- the process of removing bugs from your program.

But first you need to find those bugs.

You can do that in different ways:

- Sprinkling your code with logging/tracing statements: this is called "printf debugging".
- Thinking really hard.
- Using a **debugger**, which allows you to step through your program, pausing it (using breakpoints) and looking at the current values of the variables in it.

Once you've *found* the bug, you need to *remove* it. For that, you go back to your text editor and fix the code. That part doesn't use the debugger.

But, these days, most programmers use a combined editor/debugger (an IDE).

Comment: Removing Bug is the work of debugging ?
 I mean I am not getting the real purpose of Debugger - is it for fixing or finding ?

Comment: @NileshJadav A bug is an error in software logic or syntax.  To remove a bug is to fix that error. This is commonly referred to as debugging.  [De-](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/de-) being the prefix that indicates a removal of the word it is appended to, "bug".  Debugging is the process or toolset used to remove errors from software.  Programmers follow these processes and use these tools.

Answer (score 0):

In particular, a "debugger" is a software tool that allows you launch another program *(the program that is being debugged),* and to observe it while it is running.  You can, for example, set "breakpoints" which will cause the program to stop at a particular point, and you can then observe the values in CPU registers, memory, and so forth.

You can't *fix* bugs in the debugger, but you can *find* them.

Having said all that, *I* almost never use these tools.  I find that "printf debugging" (as Nilesh put it ...) is much more useful.

Comment: Yeah man ! That is what I am saying in the college, but no one is with me debugging is the process for finding the error and  according to the error it will be resolved. It is MCQ  - For Finding error in Software Code - 1 ) Debugging 2) Testing